# how can i use 1 contextmenustrip on many buttons

Tags: c#, .net, button, contextmenustrip

my Program has many buttons.
i like to use "1" contextmenustrip when i right click on a button you get a options like "change color red".
my problem is that i dont know how to code this for all the button.

```
    private void changeColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.BackColor = Color .Red;
}
```

now i can change the color for 1 button but if i need this to do with all the buttons it takes a long time and i need to use more than 1 contextmenustrip.
so i need to change the color from the button that you right click.

i am sorry for my bad english if it is not clear i will try to explain it again.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SourceControl() property of the main ContextMenuStrip to determine which button was the source of the event:

```
    private void changeColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctl = contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;
        ctl.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: sounds good but i get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  ctl = null.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i have found my solution.